# duplicating entries in listagg function

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, hierarchical-query

i have a table in which two fields are id, controlflag.It looks like

```
Id    CntrlFlag       
121   SSSSSRNNNSSRSSNNR
122   SSSNNRRSSNNRSSSSS           
123   RRSSSNNSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
```

I have to get output in the following form( the occurences of R)

```
Id    Flag
121   6,12,17
122   6,7,12
123   1,2
```

I tried oracle query( as i obtained from this forum):

```
select  mtr_id,listagg(str,',') within group (order by lvl) as flags from
 ( select  mtr_id, instr(mtr_ctrl_flags,'R', 1, level) as str, level as lvl             
    from mer_trans_reject           
    connect by level <= regexp_count(mtr_ctrl_flags, 'R'))group by mtr_id;
```

it gives the result but 2nd and 3rd occurrences(not 1st one) are duplicated a no. of times.
it looks like

```
id   Flag
123 6,12,12,12,12,17,17,17,17,17.
```

Can anybody know what's wrong here?

Comment: It could be avoided by select distinct keyword.Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

> It could be avoided by select distinct keyword.Is there any other way?

Yes, there is, but this one is a little bit heavier(distinct will cost you less):

```
with t1(Id1, CntrlFlag) as(
  select 121, 'SSSSSRNNNSSRSSNNR'      from dual union all
  select 122, 'SSSNNRRSSNNRSSSSS'      from dual union all
  select 123, 'RRSSSNNSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS' from dual
)
select w.id1
     , listagg(w.r_pos, ',') within group(order by w.id1) as R_Positions
  from (select q.id1 
             , regexp_instr(q.CntrlFlag,'R', 1, t.rn) as r_pos
          from t1 q
         cross join (select rownum rn
                       from(select max (regexp_count(CntrlFlag, 'R')) ml
                              from t1
                            )
                           connect by level <= ml      
                      ) t
         ) w  
where w.r_pos > 0                          
group by w.id1
```

Result:

```
 ID1        R_POSITIONS
----------  -----------
       121  12,17,6
       122  12,6,7
       123  1,2
```