# SQL: Parse Comma-delimited string and use as join

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I parsed a string comma-delimited string from a column in Oracle database and use each one as join to another table

example:

```
     Table 1                    Table 2

 ID      Name                  ID       Rate
 ---    ------                ----     ------
 1,2,3  FISRT                   1        90
                                2        80      
                                3        70
```

Would like to extract each ID from Table 1 to join in Table 2, something like

```
extract(tbl1.ID, i) = tbl2.ID
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't be storing values like that in the first place. Did you consider fixing your datamodel?

Comment: As much as I wanted to, but I can't

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse varchar2 to table (Oracle)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17582006/parse-varchar2-to-table-oracle)

Comment: This is not exactly what you're asking, but might be of some help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13580245/sending-an-array-of-values-to-oracle-procedure-to-use-in-where-in-clause

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting a delimited string (or column) to rows in Oracle using a pre-defined system function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825356/converting-a-delimited-string-or-column-to-rows-in-oracle-using-a-pre-defined)

Comment: I think my question is not duplicate of the questions you suggested since I need not only parsing the comma-delimited string, but I also need to find a way to use the parsed result in joins

Comment: Once you've parsed it then of course you can use it in a join...

Comment: @Ben It's not completly trivial, and quite inefficient to go from the function described in Klas's link to a join.  And lanthe does not actually need to parse the string.  It's easier to look for substrings.

Comment: It is trivial @Taemyr; you get a column back and the results are shown in the answer. I never said it was efficient; everything to do with parsing delimited strings in a RDBMS is highly _inefficient_ when compared to a simple JOIN.

Comment: @Ben As the answer notes, SYS.DBMS_DEBUG_VC2COLL, does not create a column.  You get a table for each value you pass.  So the join condition would be somethin like ...tbl2.ID in (Select column_value from table(SYS.DBMS_DEBUG_VC2COLL(tbl1.ID))

Comment: One you've selected from the table @Taemyr you have a column; using a with clause as per the answer makes this fairly obvious how to use it. I would avoid an IN statement.

Comment: I am unsure how you avoid that IN statement.

Comment: You can use a JOIN @Taemyr; http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/22b80/3

Comment: @Ben Yes, you can join against the elements in the column you create.  But when the data comes from a table you need to create that column for each entry in the original table.  So your way of formating the query at least needs a severe rewrite.  -  And I am still not sure how that should be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13580861/1083652)  you can do something like this

```
select *
from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on ','||t1.id||',' like '%,'||t2.id||',%'
```

[here is a sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1925d/1)

Answer (score 0):

The typical way is the use a hierarchical query and REGEXP_SUBSTR. If you have one row then this is okayish; if you have multiple then you've got problems.

The following will parse the comma-delimited string.

```
 select regexp_substr(:txt, '[^,]+', 1, level)
   from dual
connect by regexp_substr(:txt, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null
```

However, if you're doing more than one at once you will need to add a DISTINCT see [duplicating entries in listagg function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968016/duplicating-entries-in-listagg-function/17971170#17971170).

You can then use this in your JOIN.

```
with the_rows as (
 select distinct regexp_substr(col, '[^,]+', 1, level) as id
   from table1
connect by regexp_substr(col, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null
        )
 select *
   from table2 a
   join the_rows b
     on a.id = b.id
```

This is a horrible way to do it; you're using hierarchical queries and then a sort unique for the DISTINCT. It is about as far from efficient as you can get. You need to normalise your table.

Comment: Thanks Ben for the answer, the performance is really so bad... :( is there any other way to do it?

Comment: A.B. Cade's answer will also work but you'll be full-scanning table2 for every query. You have to normalise your database @Ianthe.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the ideas and comments, maybe I do not really need to join the parsed strings. I found somnething like "REGEXP_LIKE", below is what I tried, will this the same as I joined the 2 tables?

```
SELECT t2.id, t2.rate
  FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
    WHERE (REGEXP_LIKE(t1.id,
                ',' || t2.id || ',|^' || t2.id || ',|,' || t2.id ||
                '$|^' || t2.id || '$'))
```